# The best way to Create A dropdown menu in React Native

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, drop-down-menu

I am a newbee. Trying to add something like a dropdown list of option to one of my views in React Native app. Have been searching everywhere and here as well, but seems like everyone trying different stuff but most of them do not work coz they r out of date or simply wrong. Read something about picker but unsure.

Prefer to have a fully customisable menu that can be positioned and restyled.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this library?  https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had a look through that package. That is not what i am lookign for. I would like to use jsut asimple dropdown list that could be located anywhere in the view and is fully customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as a result. I have not found ant decent solution, so just used touchableopacity as 3 different buttons insted of a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the react-native git hub repository, in there you can find you want exactly
https://github.com/facebook/react-native

Comment: I had a look through there but i cannot find what i am looking for, maybe i am searchinG for a wrong thing. Could you please advice what exactly should i look for?

Comment: you can use this npm modal to your drop down, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-dropdown

Comment: I had a look through this package and installed. But cannot find a good explanation of hwo to use it.